# GPG Error while downloading software: "Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'"

Tags: apt, 13.10, gnupg

After installing Ubuntu 13.10 I try to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` or any software, it shows me:

```
E: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication
```

Comment: I am presently bumping into a similar issue with the CRAN repository. I am connected to a home network.

Answer (score 3):

**Does the network require authentication?**

Actually I had the same issue. This caused by the network proxy and you have to check your network connection settings.

Comment: I get this error if I am some public wifi and have not opened a web browser and agreed to the terms of service.