# "GPG Error: Clearsigned file isn't valid" When Installing Mongodb

Tags: apt, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb using [these instructions](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/).

I get to the step where you do `sudo apt-get update` and most of this runs just fine until I get the error as follows.

```
E: GPG error: http://downlaods-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease: 
 Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

This means I can't continue with the installation. Is there any way I can fix this? I am completely lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPG Error while downloading software: "Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367748/gpg-error-while-downloading-software-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nodata) and [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are better off following the instructions here - the package names have now been updated to reflect the company name change from 10gen to MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Then, assuming you copied and pasted the error you are getting, you have a typo in your URL: downlaods-distro.mongodb.org should be downloads-distro.mongodb.org - you have swapped the o and a.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that for 2 days. 
I just resolved it when I change my **VM LAN** configuration on **Virtual Box** from **NAT** to **BRIDGE**.

[Virtual Box LAN Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eniDi.png)

It my be not your problem, but after try a lot of things that I found in internet, that was my solution. And how any of those sites told me that, I had post it here.

Thanks